# Decreasing sequence of numbers generator from concrete distribution in R

Tags: r, random, sequence, normal-distribution

I'm new at R, so sorry if I'm asking a stupid question. 
I'm trying to generate random numbers from normal distribution as far as they will form a decreasing sequence of numbers, that means that the generator stops when Y_n < Y_(n+1).

I know that I have to use some for and while cycles, but I don't know how.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x <- rnorm(2)
i  <- 1
while (x[i] >= x[i+1]){
  x[i+2] <- rnorm(1)
  i <- i + 1
}
if (x[i] < x[i+1]) x <- x[1:i]
```

I'm not very excited about this code, because it grows a vector (already bad) without previously allocating the memory (also not good), but I can't think of a way to do what the OP wants without growing a vector in that way. Also, I wish there was an R word for pythonic.  This would not be it. It would not be R-ic. But it does what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
vals <- rnorm(n = 2)
idx <- length(vals)
while(vals[idx - 1] < vals[idx]) {
  vals <- append(x = vals, values = rnorm(n = 1))
  idx <- idx + 1
}
```

Comment: `append(x, values)` is a wrapper to `c(x, values)`, so you're doing the verboten `x <- c(x, "some single value")`,  in a loop. If you're adding one element, it's better r practice to add it where you want it, especially in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "with high probability" avoid growing a vector, you could generate the numbers in batches. With a batch size of 10 you're already very unlikely to have to grow a vector even once.

Performance-wise, I have no idea what's faster.

```r
rnormdec <- function(..., batch_size = 10) {
  x <- rnorm(batch_size, ...)
  decreasing <- cummax(diff(x)) < 0

  while (all(decreasing)) {
    x <- c(x, rnorm(batch_size, ...))
    decreasing <- cummax(diff(x)) < 0
  }

  x[c(TRUE, decreasing)]
}

set.seed(1)

runs <- lapply(seq_len(1e5), function(...) rnormdec(10))
table(lengths(runs))
#> 
#>     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8 
#> 49990 33311 12507  3339   714   116    20     3
```

Created on 2018-03-07 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).